# Force EntityFramework to refresh Database Context C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework

I'm building an altV gameserver and use my database(mySQL) there for all kinds of stuff, I came across the issue that the database entries get cached as soon as the Context is created. This is kind of an Issue because the data in the database changes quite often. I tried an approach where I modified the getter for my database context so it gets disposed every time i access it and gets recreated, didn't work well when adding new entries to the database. I also tried refreshing the entity, also didn't help. I'd appreciate more ideas to try :)! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is normal practice to recreate context, what issues did you have with adding new entries?

Comment: So basically what I did was modify the getter of my Database entry to always refresh everytime i access it, so when i would do dbContext.add..... that'd be a new Context, and when I do dbContext.SaveChanges(); that would be a new context again so the changes get discarded, i think I'll just move away from having a static context and will just move towards creating one everytime I need it and disposing it after

Comment: It seems that you should consider using DI and lifetime scopes.

Comment: You might try setting up your read queries as ```AsNoTracking```, and then any write queries would need to pull the specific data that needs updated again just ahead of the write operation, make updates, and persist it. [See docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) to get started. You'll likely have to experiment a little to get a feel for what the change tracker is actually doing. As a side effect your read queries will go faster though, as the memory cache for change tracking doesn't need to be set for each read  query.

Comment: In general, not only do you get answers that are more to the point when you add snippets of code while explaining the difficulties you are encoutering but the question itself becomes more useful to other people.